# How can i make check for empty string to be considered as truthy value

Tags: javascript

In js empty string is considered as falsy value.

```
let str = '';

if (str) {
  alert('success')
} else {
  alert('failure')
}
```

i get printed failure.

I have a scenario where i want to consider everything as falsy value in my string except ''.

Is there other way except with this explicit checking ?

```
if (str == '') {
```

Comment: why don't you check the type instead ? ex: `if (typeof str === 'string') { ... }`

Comment: Why not do `if(str || str === '')`

Comment: @HaoWu—because the OP wants *str* to evaluate to false if `str.length > 0`, so `typeof str == 'string' && !str.length`.

Comment: @RobG I thought what OP wanted is letting every falsy to be `false` except for `''`.

Comment: @HaoWu—I guess it depends on what you think "*I want to consider everything as falsy value in my string except ''*" means. I figured it means `!str` where *str* is a string.

Answer (score 2):

This should help '!

```
let str = '';

if (!str) {
  console.log('success')
} else {
 console.log('failure')
}
```

Comment: This will return 'success' if *str* is any falsey value such as null, undefined, 0, etc.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be the solution to your problem, simply use

Boolean(str);

Answer (score 0):

Use `!str` in your conditional stmt, which equates to *is not*.

```js
let str = '';
if(!str){
  console.log(false)
}else{
  console.log(true)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want an empty string to return true and everything else false, then:

```
!String(str)
```

does the job. But there might be certain values of *str* (e.g. reference to a host object perhaps) that are not strings where the above will return true.

A slightly shorter version is:

```
!(''+str)
```

But

```
str === ''
```

seems what you're actually after.